# Handling Complex Objects in Asp Web API

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, rest

How can I post multiple complex objects in a post request in asp web api? Everything that I seem to find suggests that only one object type is allowed in the body of the request. Is this correct? If so what is a decent workaround for this? 
   Sample Model:

```
public class Object1
{
    int numWheels { get; set; }
    string seatheight { get; set; }
    public Object2[] shopLoc { get; set; }
}

public class Object2 
{
    string streetName { get; set; }
    double revenue { get; set; }
}
Sample Products controller:
Post:products/Post/
public Object1 Post(Object1 tricycle, Object2 cyclingShop)
{
return tricycle;
}
```

How would I use this with asp web api?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you already have a property of type `Object2` in the `Object1` so why do you want to have `Object2` as separate param?

i would not have it as the array type instead have Object2 as `Enumerable` prop of `Object1` like

```
public class Object1
{
    int numWheels { get; set; }
    string seatheight { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Object2> shopLoc { get; set; }
}
```

having done that in the view(strongly typed) you can render it like

```
<%@ Page Inherits="ViewPage<Object1>" %>

<% for (int i = 0; i < Model.shoploc.Count(); i++) { %>

  <%: Html.TextBoxFor(m => m[i].streetName) %>
  <%: Html.TextBoxFor(m => m[i].revenue ) %>
<% } %>
```

if you have more than one shop locations then the Default model binder will bind the collection of shops just fine

the `POST` Action should look like

```
public Object1 Post(Object1 tricycle)
{
return tricycle;
}
```

## [A Good Read](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx)